# Making an options menu in a Windows command script

Tags: batch-file

I currently have the following Windows command script. I want to create a menu that displays all the available event types rather than having to enter them manually. The user of the script should just have to enter a number.

```
@echo off
set /p customerID="Enter Customer ID: "
set /p event="Enter Event Name: "

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "sourceFolder=C:\test"
set "targetFolder=C:\test2"

set "customerID=%customerID%"
set "event=%event%"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    findstr /m /s /l /c:"%customerID%" "%sourceFolder%\*" 
    ^| findstr /f:/ /m /l /c:"%event%"
') do (
   copy "%%~fa" "%targetFolder%"
)
pause
```

Comment: Do you have a list of _all the available event types_? Or  where such a list might come from?

Comment: This is not a quite specific question, it is rather broad. Please read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to use this site!

Comment: If there are more than 10 unique event types, you're better off with the way you currently have it set up.

Comment: You can take a look at this for creating [Batch-Menus](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsMenu.php)